# SSL certificate issue in SOAP webservice from Windows commandline

Tags: java, web-services, security, ssl, soap

When I run the Java project on eclipse, It is able to access the application server thru SOAP Web service. But I am getting SSL certificate issue while running it as JAR file from command prompt. I also verified the imported certificate. I am wondering why it is failing on command prompt only. Anything needs to be configured? Please advise.

```
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop>java -jar Javaapp.jar
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@4ec6a292
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FilterOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.StringRequestEntity.writeReques
t(StringRequestEntity.java:150)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequ
estBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:495)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodB
ase.java:1973)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.j
ava:993)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(Htt
pMethodDirector.java:397)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMe
thodDirector.java:170)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:396)
        at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.jav
a:324)
        at com.thunderhead.utility.Thunderheadrelease.sendHTTPPostRequest(Thunde
rheadrelease.java:280)
        at com.thunderhead.utility.Thunderheadrelease.main(Thunderheadrelease.ja
va:108)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali
d certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Sour
ce)
        ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown
Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
        ... 27 more
Status Code : -1
Status Code:-1
Post Request Failed - null
```

Comment: You need to include the root certificate of the server in the trust store used by your JVM (the default is jre/lib/security/cacerts)

Comment: Thanks. The certificate was already imported using keytool -import -trustcacerts.

Comment: Then review you are using the right JVM or that you didnt set a different truststore in eclipse execution

Comment: Yeah there was multiple JRE versions on the machine. we copied the certificate to the latest version. It works fine now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: should I post it as an answer?

Comment: you can..I will accept the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception means that the JVM could not validate the server certificate.
It is needed to include the root certificate of the server certificate in the trust store used by your JVM and ensure you are using the right JVM

The default truststore is located in `jre/lib/security/cacerts` of the JVM home. Also can be configured with `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/trusstore`